Modelo EER Conceptos sobre relaciones N:M
Estoy preparando unos apuntes y hay varios conceptos que todavía me hago un lío.
Por mucho que busco no consigo dar con la diferencia exacta que me sirva para todos los ejemplos que se me ocurre implementar.
¿Cuando una relación N:M es una entidad asociativa y cuando no?
¿Cuando una relación N:M es una relación identificatoria y cuando no?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Creo que en 30 años de esto nunca escuche esos conceptos.. podes agregar algun ejemplo???

Yo llevo 20 y ahora que estoy preparando nuevos apuntes, surgen estas cosas. He visto varios ejemplos, pero ninguno me deja claro que una relación n:M es una entidad asociativa. Te explico uno y me cuentan. Si tengo una relacion n:M que tiene atributos propios, por ejemplo un alumno puede hacer muchos cursos y cada curso puede ser hecho por muchos alumnos. Pero el atributo nota va en la relación. A eso se le llama entidad asociativa. Lo de identificatoria es la parte que se me complica más. Dicen que cuando la n:M usa las ajenas como ID es identificatoria, y cuando tiene ID propio No lo es...

Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues ese ejemplo con más detalles. Hay que entender que muchos conceptos en informática no cuentan con un estándar formal. Por ejemplo, UML tiene un organismo detrás que indica como debe ser, en cambio no pasa lo mismo para modelos ER y en estos casos existen variaciones de definición e implementación según el autor. Sin ir más lejos, lo que tú llamas "entidad asociativa" yo lo conocía como "tabla intermedia" y en wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entidad_asociativa puede verse que tiene otros 10 nombres distintos

Gracias yussef. Sí este mundo me tiene loco. Multitud de variantes y mucha bibliografía que no te aclara la que usa o las mezcla sin decírtelo. Las siguientes dudas trataré de poner el dibujo para ayudar con la explicación. Muchas gracias por tus aportes
